# What is App Engine's Cloud Storage Client Library default retry logic?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to find out what's the default retry logic of App Engine's [Cloud Storage Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/).

From the [RetryParams docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/retryparams_class) and the link above it "feels" like there is some default retry logic.

Yet the [source code here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/python/src/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.py#L50) indicates otherwise.

Does someone knows a definite answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `retry_params` is not specified, it uses the default here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/python/src/cloudstorage/rest_api.py#L146

The default settings can be seen here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/python/src/cloudstorage/api_utils.py#L210-L215

pasted for posterity:

```
backoff_factor=2.0,
initial_delay=0.1,
max_delay=10.0,
min_retries=3,
max_retries=6,
max_retry_period=30.0,
```